# wget of redis is not working in docker container with Debian 9 on Ubuntu host

Tags: networking, dns, docker, wget

I have a very simple Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:11
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

And I have 2 machines with Ubuntu.

**First machine:** Ubuntu 18.04.1, Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
In the docker container everything is working well:

```
root@26583a6b6e61:/# wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
--2020-01-29 14:29:34--  http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
Resolving download.redis.io (download.redis.io)... 109.74.203.151
Connecting to download.redis.io (download.redis.io)|109.74.203.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2023006 (1.9M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘redis-stable.tar.gz’

redis-stable.tar.gz 100%[ ...]   1.93M  --.-KB/s    in 0.05s
2020-01-29 14:29:34 (39.0 MB/s) - ‘redis-stable.tar.gz’ saved [023006/2023006]
```

**Second machine** Ubuntu 18.04.3, Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
--2020-01-29 14:33:14--  http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
Resolving download.redis.io (download.redis.io)... 109.74.203.151
Connecting to download.redis.io (download.redis.io)|109.74.203.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-01-29 14:33:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

If I execute the same wget on the host machine, it is working well.
It is not DNS issue, because both wget show the same IP.

What may be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the host iptables.

Comment: And what was wrong with the  iptables? :/